# Apache Camel - how to handle exception before default handler?

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

I have a simplistic Camel setup:

```
            final MyErrorProcessor myErrorProcessor = new MyErrorProcessor(10);

            onException(FooException.class)
                    .bean(myErrorProcessor, "process")
                    .redeliveryDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
                    .maximumRedeliveries(10);

            from(MIDDLE_QUEUE)
                    .bean(ProcessorBean.class, "process")
                    .to(resultEndpoint)
                    .end();
```

Where myErrorProcessor is just a bean that I want to invoke right after getting an exception.

The problem is that I get myErrorProcessor.process() executed only when all retryes fail, but I would like just to count exceptions, even if they were retried successfully.

I know that there is .onRedelivery() but it has similar problem: it invoke my bean only after redeliveryDelay, not at the moment of exception was thrown.

So, my question is: is there any way to notify my custom bean when exception was caught by Camel, without removing retry policy?

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove the redelivery from your FooException and then have your custom bean run its processing and rethrow the exception after its processing?  Then a separate exception handle can do the redelivery?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: If it will rethrow in a custom processor, I'll get back to the same onException(), right?

Comment: You might need two exception handlers, one for Fooexception and one for Barexception.  You can throw Foo, catch it and do your custom processing and then throw Barexception.  The Barexception would handle redelivery.